# Android How to put Map<V,T> in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `Map` object and I want to put it in an intent to start a `Service`:

```
Map<Integer, String> modules = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Intent downloadServiceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DownloadService.class);
downloadServiceIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_MODULE", modules);
context.startService(downloadServiceIntent);
```

I think I could break the `Map` into two arrays (`int[]` and `String[]`), then put them in intent. For example:

```
int[] keys = new int[modules.size()];
String[] values = new String[modules.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : modules.entrySet()) {
    keys[i] = entry.getKey();
    values[i] = entry.getValue();
    i++;
}
downloadServiceIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEYS", keys);
downloadServiceIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_VALUES", values);
```

Is it a good idea? Is there any alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: You do realize right Bundle in itself is a mini Map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put a serializable as extra [1]. And HashMap for example does implement the serializable interface [2]. So if you change your variable type from Map to HashMap you can put your map directly as extra.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)
[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes your idea is good. There is no way to put the Map in Intent.