# Send Map data in an intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to send `Map` interface data in an intent, I searched all over but I found how to send `HashMap` which is an implementation of Map but can anyone please tell me how can I send this interface values in an intent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android How to put Map<V,T> in an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265292/android-how-to-put-mapv-t-in-an-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already using Gson library so I serialised my `Map` into a `String` and then again in the catching activity I deserialised it.

**Passing Activity**

```
Map data;
intent.putExtra("map", new Gson().toJson(data));
```

**Catching Activity**

```
Map data = new Gson().fromJson(intent.getExtras().getString("map"), Map.class);
```